# Android Null Pointer Exception ListFragment

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I cannot figure out what to do to fix this Null Pointer Exception I am getting. `mButton.setText("Hi");` is what triggers it. I have tried looking at other questions but I have not been able to get it to work. Here is my code:

ContactsTab.java

```
public class ContactsTab extends ListFragment implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    private CustomAdapter mAdapter;
    private Cursor mCursor;
    private String currentQuery;
    private Button mButton;
    private static final String[] PROJECTION = {
            Contacts._ID,
            Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY,
            Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY,
            Contacts.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI,
            Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER,
    };
    private static final String[] FROM = { Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY };
    private static final int[] TO = { R.id.contact_text };
    private static final String SELECTION = "(" + Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = 1) AND (" + Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " != 0 )";



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.contacts_tab, container, false);
        mButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.badge);
        mButton.setText("Hi");
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mCursor = null;
        mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.contacts_list_item, mCursor, FROM, TO, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
        getListView().setDivider(null);
        getListView().setDividerHeight(0);
    }

    ...

}
```

contacts_tab.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/contacts_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</ListView>
```

contacts_list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/badge"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_button"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="42dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contact_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:textColor="@color/grey_dark"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace/logs?

Comment: I think it is quite clear that you have not made any button object for mButton. you just make a reference to a null . I am not android expert but I do not see how (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.badge); produces button object for you?!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this in your adapter, not in the fragment. In the adapter, you will have a reference to each one of the items of the listview.

Answer (score 2):

By code

```
View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.contacts_tab, container, false);
mButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.badge);
mButton.setText("Hi");
```

you are trying to get `Button`, which is part of `contacts_tab.xml`, but in this xml you don't have any buttons.

You have button in your adapter list item and you need to get reference to that button using adapter.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Anand Singh answer, using a `ListFragment` requires a specific layout with predefined ListView id:

> ListFragment has a default layout that consists of a single list view. However, if you desire, you can customize the fragment layout by returning your own view hierarchy from onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle).
>
> To do this, your view hierarchy must contain a ListView object with the id "@android:id/list" (or list if it's in code)

For more please look at [ListFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html) documentation.